# Orchestrating GCP Cloud Functions

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, serverless, azure-durable-functions

How do you Orchestrate Functions in GCP? what is the AWS Step Functions or Azure Durable Functions equivalent in GCP? Is there one, I couldn't find because Cloud Functions won't do it?

Comment: Can you please add some more context in what you're trying to achieve? At the moment, it's difficult to answer the question in the way you have asked it. Please take a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I was checking to see if anyone knows what is the equivalent service in GCP for AWS Step Functions or Azure Durable functions? The context here is I need to do a workflow of different functions which could have manual process like approvals too. I hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/). The tool lets you organise your workflows and it's based on Apache Airflow. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Siamsot this is what I was looking for! How to do these Cloud vendor find ways to name their products:)